# NodeJS MSSQL REST Connection Closed Error

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express, cluster-computing

I build a rest api with NodeJS.
It is using the modules cluster, express ,body-parser, mssql.
The solution is working fine but sometimes the result is the sql error: The server closed the connection.

Does anyone know a solution. I read about mssql promise of the promise module but how does i implement this and is this a good solution.

When the database server gives the error: The server closed the connection i want automatic retry (Open SQL DB Connection and execute query).

```
var cluster = require('cluster');


if (cluster.isMaster) {


var cpuCount = require('os').cpus().length;


for (var i = 0; i < cpuCount; i += 1) {
    cluster.fork();
}


cluster.on('exit', function (worker) {

    // Replace the dead worker, we're not sentimental
    console.log('Worker %d died:', worker.id);
    cluster.fork();

});


} else {


var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var sql = require("mssql");
var app = express(); 


app.use(bodyParser.json()); 


app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    //Enabling CORS 
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, contentType,Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    next();
});


 var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8000, function () {
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log("App now running on port", port);
 });


var dbConfig = {
    user:  "<USER>",
    password: "<PASSWORD>",
    server: "<SERVER>",
    database: "<DB>",
    connectionTimeout: 999999999,
    requestTimeout: 999999999,
    pool: {
            max: 20,
            min: 10,
            idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
        },
    options: {
            encrypt: true
        }
};


var  executeQuery = function(res, query){     

     sql.connect(dbConfig, function (err, connection) {
         if (err) {   
                     console.log("Error while connecting database :- " + err);
                     res.send(err);
                     res.end();
                  }
                  else {

                         var request = new sql.Request(connection);

                         request.query(query, function (err, rs) {
                           if (err) {
                                      console.log("Error while querying database :- " + err);
                                      res.send(err);
                                      res.end();
                                     }
                                     else {
                                            console.log("Result :- " + rs); 
                                            res.send(rs);
                                            res.end();
                                            }
                               });
                         sql.close();      
                       }
      }); 


}


 app.post("/ic/events/add", function(req , res){
                var query = "INSERT INTO EVENT VALUES ('FILE')";
                executeQuery (res, query);
});


 app.post("/ic/process/to", function(req , res){
                var query = "SELECT TOP 1 FROM EVENT WHERE STATUS = 0";
                executeQuery (res, query);
});

}
```

Kind regards,

Mark

Comment: But Cody G, The connection is only open when a query is  executed and after the result i close the connection directly. Or do I miss something

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read that closely! I see

Comment: I hightly recommend async/await https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql

Comment: But how do I implement this in mine app?

Comment: You follow the documentation; is there any place you're having trouble getting started? You can use async/await inside of an async function, so generally people have a `(async function main(){})()` they create and call which really fires off the rest of the application. There's some syntax and gotchyas to learn if it's the first time you're using it.

Answer (score 0):

I will thank you for your help. I changed the app with the following code to use 1 connection. After 2 days running the app I don't have any connection closed error anymore.

```
//Initiallising connection string
var dbConfig = {
    user:  "",
    password: "",
    server: "",
    database: "",
    connectionTimeout: 999999999,
    requestTimeout: 999999999,
    options: {
            encrypt: true
        }
};



sql.connect(dbConfig, function (err, connection) {
         if (err) {   
                     console.log("Error while connecting database :- " + err);
                  }
            }); 


var  executeQuery = function(res, query, connection){     

                         // create Request object
                         var request = new sql.Request(connection);
                         // query to the database
                         request.query(query, function (err, rs) {
                           if (err) {
                                      console.log("Error while querying database :- " + err);
                                      res.send(err);
                                      res.end();
                                     }
                                     else {
                                            console.log("Result :- " + rs); 
                                            res.send(rs);
                                            res.end();
                                            }
                               });


      };
```

Answer (score -1):

Do not open a connection for every query executed. Open a connection to the database when the server starts up and use that connection for the lifetime of the app.

[Here's an article](https://itnext.io/how-to-share-a-single-database-connection-in-a-node-js-express-js-app-fcad4cbcb1e) on sharing the database connection throughout the app.

Now, if there is a disconnect at anytime while querying, then log the error to a logging system (Loggly, Rollbar), let the app die and then have a node monitor restart the app (Forever, Nodemon). The error sent to the log might give you some answers as far as what the issue is. Most likely it is a network error and your database is not accessible.

Comment: This recommendation can't be applied for all scenarios, and I don't think really provides a good answer on how to handle the connection being closed.

Comment: Agree to disagree. He shouldn't be making connections for every query. Memory is going to get overrun with connections. My experience is blips in connectivity to DB can be overcome by restarting server. The code required to maintain the connection could be complicated and cause other issues.

Comment: He closes the connection after the request is finished, which seems fine to me.